# Most simplified form of the following regex / Extracting all values from nvidia-smi output

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis, nvidia, nvidia-smi

I am trying to analyze very large text string in Python containing nvidia-smi outputs but I really want to spend more time analyzing the data than working on my regex skills. I got the regex as follows but it takes forever in some rows (it might be the variation of input data in some rows), but I thought maybe my regex pattern is very compute-intensive as well.

```
extracted_line1 = r'[=]*[+][=]*[+][=]*\|\n\|(\s+(.*?)\|)+\n\|(\s+(.*?)\|)(\s+(.*?)\|)(\s+(.*?)\|)\n\|'
```

This pattern matches the third row in the table.

This one down below ⬇️

```
 ===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   20C    P8     6W / 180W |      2MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
```

It works for most rows but randomly hangs for some rows. What would be a more simplified version of this regex expression? Or maybe a better question is what is the best approach to grab each of the values in this table for every row (corresponding metrics for each GPU)?

Truncated input string is here

```
... bunch of text
nvidia-smi:
Tue Jun  8 15:00:02 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   20C    P8     6W / 180W |      2MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   23C    P8     6W / 180W |      2MiB /  8119MiB |      0%   E. Process |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

... bunch of text
```

P.S I am trying to extract the following values

```
        gpu_index = [processed result of regex output here]
        gpu_model_name = [processed result of regex output here]
        persistance_mode = [processed result of regex output here]
        bus_id = [processed result of regex output here]
        display_active = [processed result of regex output here]
        volatile_ecc = [processed result of regex output here]
        fan = [processed result of regex output here]
        temperature = [processed result of regex output here]
        perf = [processed result of regex output here]
        power_usage =  [processed result of regex output here]
        max_power = [processed result of regex output here]
        memory_usage = [processed result of regex output here] 
        available_mem = [processed result of regex output here] 
        gpu_utilization = [processed result of regex output here]
        compute_mode = [processed result of regex output here]
        multiple_instance_gpu_mode = [processed result of regex output here]
```

Comment: Why not get the CSV output from `nvidia-smi` with only the data you need? `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used --format=csv` is an example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this data had already been generated by a script over the years and stored in a file and was collected from an entire GPU cluster of 200+ nodes ... Since this data is instantaneous, I have no way of going back in time to get the CSV output as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest another pattern, easier on your machine's resources.**

## Pattern

```
(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)\s+\|\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\/\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\|\s+(\d+\%)\s+(.*?)\s+\|
```

First of all, I got rid of all the starting pattern of finding `=` or `+` chars because regex knows how to find the stuff you instruct it to find. No 'helper' handles needed.

Next I found that you only need to grab a hold on english chars `\w`, digits `\d` and whitespaces `\s` and so the whole pattern was pretty easy to write.

## Explanation

I'm building the whole pattern match group by match group until reaching the final result. Please notice each explanation is only valid for the last match group i.e. `(some ReGex expresion in parantesis)`

`(\d+%)` will match any number of digits followed by `%`

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)` will match any number of digits after unknown amount of whitespaces, followed by the letter `C`

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)` will match any single char followed by any single digit

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)` will match any number of digits after unknown amount of whitespaces, followed by a single char

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)` knowing there should by some whitespaces, then `/` and some other whitespaces, this expression will match any number of digits followed by `W`

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)\s+\|\s+(\d+MiB)` knowing there should by some whitespaces, then `|` and some other whitespaces, this expression will match any number of digits followed by `MiB`

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)\s+\|\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\/\s+(\d+MiB)` knowing there should by some whitespaces, then `/` and some other whitespaces, this expression will match any number of digits followed by a `MiB`

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)\s+\|\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\/\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\|\s+(\d+\%)` knowing there should by some whitespaces, then `|` and some other whitespaces, this expression will match any number of digits followed by a `%`

### Last bit

`(\d+%)\s+(\d+C)\s+(\w\d)\s+(\d+W)\s+\/\s+(\d+W)\s+\|\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\/\s+(\d+MiB)\s+\|\s+(\d+\%)\s+(.*?)\s+\|` knowing there should by some whitespaces, this expression will match any number of any characters until it hits some unknown amount of whitespaces followed by `|`

## Finally the next variables are covered:

```
gpu_index = not implemented
gpu_model_name = not implemented
persistance_mode = not implemented
bus_id = not implemented
display_active = not implemented
volatile_ecc = not implemented
fan = (\d+%)
temperature = (\d+C)
perf = (\w\d)
power_usage =  (\d+W)
max_power = (\d+W)
memory_usage = (\d+MiB)
available_mem = (\d+MiB)
gpu_utilization = (\d+\%)
compute_mode = (.*?)
multiple_instance_gpu_mode = not implemented
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining all the steps in such a great detail. This was very helpful. I will use the match group by match group method to grab the next row up to the 8th index GPU data.